# Wrong flag as software recommendation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939761/where-to-find-objective-comparison-of-web-frameworks-features) was flagged with the following text:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." – Li357, CRice, Bergi, Willie Wheeler, Amy
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question.

I'm sure that this is a wrong flag (which does not mean that maybe is wrong because of other issue). I think so, because **I was not "*asking* (…) *to recommend*"** I just "*describe*d *the problem*" (need to select a framework) based on **specific and objective criteria**<sup>1</sup> to get a **finite and limited answer**<sup>2</sup>.

Anyway, I understand that it can look confusing, so I add a note to clarify. With some comments that insist on it, I went further: as the "question can be reworded" I did so, including "*what has been done so far to solve it*" (Wikipedia).<sup>3</sup>

How should I proceed?
Should I re-reword the question? Which part of it?

---

**Footnotes:**

1. I think that *the conditions I ask are objective* enough to avoid debate. Also, I was not pointed out what was the "debatable" part of my question. They didn't said, example, "if a framework is written in ES6 is a debatable issue". If that would be the case, I coulded rewrite that part to avoid debate.
2. From all the Javascript web frameworks (finite list, don't know size), I specify **7 conditions that make a small (even maybe empty) subset of that**.

   Maybe the initial list is big (I don't know, but Wikipedia has a short list), but **my question was very restricted to get a short list**.

---

Note that I do follow the questions in the Don't ask [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Where:

- Not every question is equally valid, it must be fact-based to meet asked criteria.
- I provide no answer (I wish, ha!).
- There is an actual problem to be solved.
- It's not an open-ended nor hypothetical.
- It's not a rant.

Comment: *"questions asking us to recommend or **find a** book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource**"* in this case, the offsite resource you want us to find for you is a comparison of web frameworks

Comment: It does not have to be off-site. I reword it because someone says about the list been infinite (which is not, I even think it is short). So, should I ask again the compairison itself?

Comment: Although I didn't get any other feedback (sad from a large community like this one), I do remove the previously added reference to off-site.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do software recommendations or lists of stuff questions. Reasons why is explained in the close reason. You're asking for a list of software. Hence, your question is off-topic.

Comment: A list of software is not a list of recommended software, @Mat. I don't care about opinions, I don't want recomendations, As "which are the ways of order the letters A, B, U" (right answer: 6) is not the same as "What is the best way to order A, B, U" (infinite subjective answers).

Comment: "Stack Overflow doesn't do software recommendations **or lists of stuff questions.**"

Comment: Where it said is does not takes "lists of stuffs". I found it odd, because a lot (maybe a majority) of the answers can be interpreted as a list. If I ask "How to redirect both stderr and stdout to a file" I'm asking a list of ways to do it.

Comment: If you are looking for an existing framework comparison, you are looking for an offsite resource. If you are looking for someone to write the comparison as an answer, your question is primarily opinion based (no matter what you think about its purported objectivity). No matter how you cut it, a bad question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ESL That's the main difference. Asking of lists of stuffs is just that, asking for a list of things. But when you ask that question, you're specifying an actual issue and wanting to figure it out. The flag says: ... Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I though that the problem was clearer, that I want to select a framework with those criteria, and I don't know where to start. I google and check Wikipedia, and it was not useful. So, how should I edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: And why do you think, @yivi, that if someone writes a comparison it would subjective? I put some criteria to avoid that.

Comment: see also: [How can Stack Overflow help developers evaluate technologies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305678/839601)

Answer (score 9):

At first sight, I do not think there is a no simple way to "rephrase" your question.

IMO it is clear that you are looking for an offsite resource.

Your final comment saying that certain Wikipedia page is not a fit answer would point that way, and the "how to find" in the title reinforces that impression.

So, all in all, the close reason is perfectly valid.

Your many comments confuse the matter a bit, so it is not perfectly clear what would be be a **correct** answer to your question (which would further point to the question being closable).

But listing the alternatives:

- You want a link to an existing comparison: Link to an offsite resource (off-topic)
- You want a list of existing frameworks: Recommendation for an (or many) off-site resource/s.
- If what you want is people helping you "choose" one of those frameworks, even without pointing you to an existing offsite comparison: opinion based and too broad (off-topic)

This kind of question is not good for StackOverflow.

Deciding which software tools you are going to use is something **only you** can do. Finding out which tools exist **is the research that you need to do**.

If you want to ask around about existing tools, great; just not in SO. There are other sites which are more conducive for that kind of conversation.

Comment: I'm not want to people help me to choose one of those frameworks, **i want to know which are those frameworks**.

Comment: I give up. I think I does not feel comfortable at Stack Overflow as I feel in others Stack Exchange (even other platforms). At least you are the first that makes me feel that you actually care, and not just want to erase the question to move to the next one.

Comment: @ESL: People do care around here. Mostly about the site than about the individual users, and that is fine.

Comment: There is no need to feel so discouraged for a closed question. If everybody is telling you that your question is not a good fit for StackOverflow, the wise thing to do is to accept it and learn form the experience, instead of trying to convince everyone that you are right and the question is fine.

Comment: This question of yours is not good for SO, but you can ask other questions here, and millions find the resource immensely useful. This question one in particular could feel more at home in a more open platform (E.g. reddit, quora, or something more forum like).

Comment: The feel is not because of closed question, it is mainly because of the way I feel this issues are addressed by some members of the community. The second problem is that I tried to learn why this is not valid while other similar answers are, but failed. The second one is about communication, there is place for me to improve there. But the first one it fells more about people. And one can't neither change other people, nor (usually) how they made feel to one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions of platforms :).

Comment: Regarding this particular issue, as it is not clear what is an invalid "list" question, the uncertanty also discourage to ask questions.

Comment: @ESL, I'm sorry but you are making this harder than it should be: you are asking for an offsite comparison list (recommendation link, off-topic). Or people to write a list as an answer (recommendation of software, off-topic). Or a list and a comparison (recommendation, opinion based, off-topic & off-topic). End of story.